# Google analytics not sending any hits in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, analytics

I created sample project and added google analytics based on google tutorial.
But when i run this app, i couldn't see any hits sending from app.

```
I have added all these libraries
1.libsqlite3.0.tbd
2.libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
3.libsqlite3.dylib
4.libz.dylibs
5.CoreData.framework
6.SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Added these library file too

```
1.GAI.h
2.GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
3.GAIEcommerceFields.h
4.GAIEcommerceProduct.h
5.GAIEcommerceProductAction.h
6.GAIEcommercePromotion.h
7.GAIFields.h
8.GAILogger.h
9.GAITrackedViewController.h
10.GAITracker.h
```

In my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GAI.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<GAITracker> tracker;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

In my AppDelegate.m file

```
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
/** Google Analytics configuration constants **/
static NSString *const kGaPropertyId = @"UA-000000-1"; // Placeholder property ID.
static NSString *const kTrackingPreferenceKey = @"allowTracking";
static BOOL const kGaDryRun = NO;
static int const kGaDispatchPeriod = 30;
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut =
    ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kTrackingPreferenceKey];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Do other work for customization after application launch
    // then initialize Google Analytics.
    [self initializeGoogleAnalytics];

    return YES;
}

- (void)initializeGoogleAnalytics {

    [[GAI sharedInstance] setDispatchInterval:kGaDispatchPeriod];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] setDryRun:kGaDryRun];
    self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:kGaPropertyId];
}
```

In my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@end
```

In my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    // This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
    // hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker set:kGAIScreenName
                                       value:@"Home Screen"];

    // Send the screen view.
    // Previous V3 SDK versions.
    // [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker
    //     send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];

    // SDK Version 3.08 and up.
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker
     send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}
```

am not able to send screen name to google analytics pls help me...

Comment: when you added this googleanalytics in your project

Comment: just now @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Is it a application Google Analytics account?    When did you create the Google Analytics account?

Answer (score 0):

use this one for `viewdidload`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
        [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:kBookingConfirmation];
        [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
    }
```

Comment: when u created app? can u create one more sample app and send me link?