# Analytic always shows "Right now 0 active users on the app"

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, analytics

I am implementing google analytic, by following guide lines here 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced#example

So all my configurations looks like this 
[Google analytics not sending any hits in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735151/google-analytics-not-sending-any-hits-in-ios)

I have created track id one week ago, dispatch interval is 1, Still no real time update. What am I missing?

Comment: Google Analtyics doesn't send hits to IOS IOs sends hits to Google Analytics.   You didn't create a web google analytics account did you?

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for replying. I have created an account there and got track id from there.

Comment: Yes but what type of account did you create? Mobile or web?

Comment: @DalmTo The app is created for Mobile apps. So What could be wrong or missing with all the setups?

Comment: Am experiencing something very similar. Oddly, tracking in our Today extension works fine and we can see realtime data for that, but we do not see realtime tracking in app.

Answer (score 0):

Adding iAd.framework to **Targets - Build phases - Link binary with libraries** helped me to resolve same issue with Xcode 8.
[image: Xcode screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @sergey I will check it.

Comment: added the iAD framework but still no real time user data.

Comment: @Devesh try to send some data to Analytics service and check debug output. For example view controller name:     `id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];` Put that code in ViewWillAppear method of some of your controllers. Don't forget to add `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`